# Is per product table shipping rate possible with magento?

Tags: magento, product

I found an extension for it but its too costly...any alternatives or modifications possible?

http://www.magentocommerce.com/magento-connect/webshopapps/extension/1357/webshopapps-product-matrix-shipping

Answer (score 0):

You can write a custom shipping method module ( Take a lookie here http://inchoo.net/ecommerce/magento/custom-shipping-method-in-magento)
But the time spent on it might be significant(Magento uses very advanced MVC paradigm)and buying it might be mosey well spent